# Issue with installing the Angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli

I installed the Angular CLI (or so I thought) using the command prompt but when I check the version, it is not there.

Keyed: cd "C:\Dans\Work 2\Tech\Dot Net\Asp.Net Core\MVC web api with                           Angular7\master\gym-project"
Hit enter.

Keyed: npm install -g @angular/cli
Hit enter.

[image]

It indicates it updated.

But when I go to check the version, It get an error and there is no 'node_modules' folder in the path as there should be.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are installing `@angular/cli` at a *global* level. This will not create a 'node_modules' folder in the current directory.

You are getting an error when you try to use `ng --version` because you are in a directory that has a `package.json` file (which I imagine has a local version of `@angular/cli` specified) but there is no local 'node_modules' folder.

Solution:

`npm i`

This will read the `package.json` file and locally install all of the node modules required for the project in a 'node_modules' folder that it will create. After that, your `ng --version` command should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a directory called `node_modules` at `C:\Dans\Work 2\Tech\Dot Net\Asp.Net Core\MVC web api with Angular7\master\gym-project"`. Then close your terminal, reopen your terminal, navigate to the above mentioned path, and issue a `ng version` and `ng help` to see if the issue persists. If it does I would reinstall angular cli.

Hopefully that helps